# What's wrong with my spring-social ConnectController?

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot app that will connect to Fitbit's api using spring-social. I've (half-way) implemented a `ConnectionFactory` and it's dependencies for Fitbit, and am trying to consume it from my app. Part of this involves starting up a `ConnectController` to handle the OAuth2 "dance".

When I try to hit the `ConnectController` through my browser at `http://localhost:8080/connect` or `http://localhost:8080/connect/fitbit` I get redirected to the whitelable error page with the message:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>
> Request method 'GET' not supported

I don't really understand what I'm seeing, but when I set `DEBUG` level logging and use some breakpoints it looks like hitting `/connect` from the browser results in Spring trying to find something called `connect/status` and hitting `/connect/fitbit` result in spring trying to find something named `/connect/fitbitConnect` and then trying to internally make a GET request to `/connect/connect/fitbitConnect`.

In both cases it looks like the methods on `ConnectController` corresponding to `/connect` and `/connect/{providerId}` get called fine, and then Spring bombs when it goes looking for all that other stuff.

Here is the `SocialConfigurer` implementation I'm using which creates the `ConnectController` bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
@PropertySource("${properties.path}/fitbot-service.properties")
public class SpringSocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(new FitbitConnectionFactory(
                environment.getProperty("fitbit.clientId"),
                environment.getProperty("fitbit.clientSecret")
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new SessionUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

}
```

What on earth is going on here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be related to your question regarding GET vs. POST in ConnectController, so you may have already answered this for yourself. Nonetheless, let me clarify why it's looking for connect/status and connect/fitbitConnect.

Those are view names. When you do a GET for /connect, you're asking ConnectController to fetch connection status for all providers and to place it in the model, after which it will forward that model to a view whose logical name is "connect/status". Usually this is a JSP at the path "/connect/status.jsp" or maybe a Thymeleaf template at "/connect/status.html", but it can be any view following the rules of whatever Spring MVC view resolvers are in play.

Likewise, a GET request for /connect/fitbit is asking ConnectController to fetch connection status for the "fitbit" provider and to place that information in the model and forward it on to a view whose name is "/connect/fitbitConnect" (if there isn't a connection) or "/connect/fitbitConnected" (if there is a connection).

Aside from answering your question, may I also request that you tell me more about your FitBit Spring Social provider project? Is it modeled after other community-led Spring Social projects? In other words, is it a standalone extension to Spring Social that others may use? If so, tell me where it is in GitHub and I'll be happy to add it to the "Community Projects" section at http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/.

Comment: (1 of 2) Thank you for also taking a look at this question. I really appreciate it. I'll look into adding those views. Regarding the app: I'm a consultant working for Target, and they let us do innovation sprints. Everyone on my teem does fitbit step count competitions, and we'd like to get info about rankings dumped into hipchat by a hubot. Spring-social-fitbit is my attempt at emulating the other spring-social projects. Target might let us post source code (and that kind of is a goal of ours), but I don't think it will be very useful

Comment: (2 of 2) I don't think our spring-social-fitbit will be a useful contribution for a couple of reasons: (1) we're only building enough functionality to get step info, (2) I barely know what I'm doing, (3) we're probably not going to finish. 

That being said, I find this stuff sufficiently interesting that I'd consider forking/restarting this as a community project. It would be the coolest thing ever if I could make a substantive contribution to Spring and get really deep into this OAuth stuff.