# Why does spring-social's ConnectController start the OAuth 2 "dance" with a POST?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-social

I'm trying to make an app that connects to Fitbit via OAuth2 using spring-social. [I've had some troubles with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188821/whats-wrong-with-my-spring-social-connectcontroller) but I think I'm figuring things out. I notice that the OAuth process is initiated by making a POST to the ConnectController. Why is this done with a POST rather than a GET? I'd like to make it so that I can drop a link into a chatroom that the user can click to authorize my app to use their Fitbit information, which means that I'd like to start things off with a GET. Is there a reason why this isn't done? If I were to make changes to this effect (by subclassing ConnectController) would I run into technical/security problems?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons:

1. The primary reason is that GET requests are expected to perform operations that are both safe and idempotent. But as a result of that request, you may (in the case of OAuth 1.0(a)) end up obtaining and possibly storing a request token as well as initializing the OAuth dance with the provider. This is not considered "safe" in the terms of a safe request. Moreover, it may or may not be idempotent, as repeating the request may result in a different behavior (depending the the provider's implementation of OAuth). While this may not apply to OAuth 2, it needed to be consistent between OAuth 1 and OAuth 2.
2. The /connect/{provider} path represents a single resource. There are only so many HTTP verbs to choose from without resorting to putting verbs into the path. The GET method for that path is already assigned to the request to fetch connection status for that provider (an operation which is both safe and idempotent).

Even so, I've encountered the use-case you're asking about. What I've done when I feel the need to have a link that kicks off the OAuth flow is to have a form that POSTs to /connect/{provider} and have some Javascript that submits the form for me, either as the result of a direct link (if the link is on a page in the app) or as the result of page load (if the link is to be given in an email or chatroom).

You're also certainly welcome to override ConnectController's behavior or even write your own implementation of the controller to meet your needs, even if they violate the reasoning behind why ConnectController is implementation the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! These are exactly the sort of details I'm looking for. I've also seen the POST a form technique recommended a few places. A follow up question RE#2: Is /connect/{provider} in any way essential to the OAuth2 dance? I.e. does killing/changing it result in the ConnectController being unable to do it's job OAuth-wise?

Comment: I'm playing with Spring Social to connect via Facebook provider but I'm wondering when hitting /connect with POST what's the payload that. we must send in the request's body ?